# The Mirth production channel goes pooling when reading files from SFTP

Tags: mirth

I have a Mirth channel that reads files (.pdf files) from an SFTP location and then transfers those files into another SFTP location. The channel shows pooling (under "Connection log" in the Mirth Dashboard) in the production environment and does not read and process any files. However, the same channel (same settings) works well in the staging environment. I have checked, the SFTP location can be accessed from the server that Mirth installed and can be accessed from the Mirth environment as well. The settings are identical both production and staging environment. The interval time set in both environments is 2 minutes. However, I have changed the production interval time to 10 mins to check the issue, it didn't help. Seems like the issue is at reading location in the production environment. What would be the reason for pooling the channel?

Comment: Need more info but I'd take a look at file permission on the production server.

Comment: I checked the permission, I can copy/paste files to SFTP location. However, I redeployed the channel in the Mirth and it starts to work.

Comment: Is the account that the mirth service runs under the same between both environments?

Comment: Yes. The same account uses to access both environments. I hope you inquired about seeing the account permission.